# Mule xpath function

Tags: mule, xpath-2.0

I have an xml like below

```
<wd:report xmlns:wd="foo">  
  <wd:id>abc</wd:id>  
  <wd:id>def</wd:id>  
  <wd:id>ghi</wd:id> 
</wd:report>
```

I am using an xpath 2 function to concatenate the wd:id elements as below

```
#[xpath3('string-join(//wd:id)')]
```

and this works except that I need to have a semicolon delimiter between the strings like abc;def;ghi. So when I use the below function

```
#[xpath3('string-join(//wd:id, ';')')]
```

I get an xpath parsing exception saying an unexpected token ) found . How can I avoid the error? Thanks.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your expression should look like this:`#[xpath3('string-join(//wd:id, ";")')]`

important part is `"` vs `'`